# Theoretical constraints of relativity on dispersion relations

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, causality, dispersion

A wave has a dispersion relation $\omega=\omega(\vec{k})$. (The function has been made single valued usinng initial conditions.) A delta function in the origin at $t=0$ ( $\psi(\vec{x},0)=\delta(\vec{x})$ ) evolves in time  and space as
$$\psi(\vec{x},t)=\int d^n\vec{k}\frac{e^{i(\vec{k}.\vec{x}-\omega(\vec{k})t)}}{(2\pi)^{n}}$$
But at $|\vec{x}|>ct$ there should be no sign of the wave and hence we must have
$$\int d^n\vec{k}\hspace{2mm}e^{i(\vec{k}.\vec{x}-\omega(\vec{k})t)}=0\hspace{5mm}\forall |\vec{x}|>ct$$
Translate this condition to a more direct condition on the dispersion relation.

Remark: It is easy to come up with examples of dispersion relations which have both group and phase velocity less than $c$ but do not satisfy this more strict relation.